# Debugging in WebStorm broke after new update (#WS-183.5912.23)

Tags: debug, webstorm

I recently updated JetBrains WebStorm and I find myself unable to debug Node.JS scripts, debugging using Chrome seems to work fine, React-Native debugging works, but when I try to debug a Node script such as the following:

```
console.log("hello world");
```

where a breakpoint is set on the first line, the debugger never starts and returns the following message in the console:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: Schneider\AppData\Local\Temp\debugConnector.183.5912.23.js is not supported in NODE_OPTIONS
```

It may be noteworthy to mention 2 things:

a) My username (Windows) contains a space,

b) I accidentally deleted the `C:\Users\Jacob Schneider\.WebStorm2018.3` folder located in my home directory.

I've looked, even on the official bug list, but it doesn't seem to be known of, there isn't even a setting for it. Does anyone know how I can return the Node.JS debugging functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreated, logged as [WEB-37804](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37804). Please follow this ticket for updates.

As a workaround, please try disabling `js.debugger.use.node.options` key in **Registry**:

- in **Help | Find action**, type *Registry* to locate it
- in **Registry**, find `js.debugger.use.node.options` key, clear the checkbox next to it

[image]